# php fatal error class illuminate\console\command not found

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a web application deployed through Elastic Beanstalk. The web app was developed using PHP 7 and Laravel framework (Zend Engine v3.0.0)

This is the error i am getting:
php fatal error class illuminate\console\command not found

php -i on the EC2 instance does not list illuminate but illuminate is there in /var/app/current/vendor/laravel/framework/src

Any help would be highly appreciated. Many thanks!

Comment: run `composer install` & `composer dump-autoload` and see how it goes

Comment: Illuminate has been made into its own component so it may not have a correct reference in your `composer.json` file.

Comment: composer dump-autoload gave me : Cannot create cache directory /root/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/, or directory is not writable. Proceeding without cache Cannot create cache directory /root/cache/files/, or directory is not writable. Proceeding without cache Generating optimized autoload files [ErrorException] file_put_contents(/var/app/current/vendor/composer/autoload_namespaces.php): failed to open stream: Permission denied dump-autoload [--no-scripts] [-o|--optimize] [-a|--classmap-authoritative] [--apcu] [--no-dev] –

Comment: composer install gave me : Cannot create cache directory /root/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/, or directory is not writable. Proceeding without cache Cannot create cache directory /root/cache/files/, or directory is not writable. Proceeding without cache Loading composer repositories with package information Installing dependencies (including require-dev) from lock file Nothing to install or update [ErrorException]file_put_contents(/var/app/current/vendor/composer/installed.json): failed to open stream: Permission denied